# Brownie Python .env file Error export variable is not working?

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, brownie

This pertains to Patrick Collins' "Solidity, Blockchain, and Smart Contract Course – Beginner to Expert Python Tutorial" on youtube.

```
    [This is my .env file][1]
    
    
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrw9C.png
```

This is my brownie-config.yaml

```
dotenv : .env

wallets:
  from_key : ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

I tried opening a new project(s) on Infura.io and added a new project ID to the .env but it didn't help.

This is Error Logs

```
    ERROR LOGS
    
    C:\Users\Project\soltest>brownie run scripts/main.py --network rinkeby
    INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
    Brownie v1.19.0 - Python development framework for Ethereum
    
    SoltestProject is the active project.
    
    Running 'scripts\main.py::main'...
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 51, in main
        return_value, frame = run(
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 110, in run
        return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
      File ".\scripts\main.py", line 33, in main
        con()
      File ".\scripts\main.py", line 19, in con
        Simple_Storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from":account})
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 549, in __call__
        return tx["from"].deploy(
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 510, in deploy
        receipt, exc = self._make_transaction(
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 720, in _make_transaction
        gas_price, gas_strategy, gas_iter = self._gas_price(gas_price)
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 456, in _gas_price
        return web3.eth.generate_gas_price(), None, None
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 986, in generate_gas_price
        return self._generate_gas_price(transaction_params)
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 213, in _generate_gas_price
        return self.gasPriceStrategy(self.web3, transaction_params)
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\web3\gas_strategies\rpc.py", line 20, in rpc_gas_price_strategy
        return web3.manager.request_blocking(RPC.eth_gasPrice, [])
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 197, in request_blocking
        response = self._make_request(method, params)
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 150, in _make_request
        return request_func(method, params)
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
        response = make_request(method, params)
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\web3\middleware\gas_price_strategy.py", line 90, in middleware
        return make_request(method, params)
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
        response = make_request(method, params)
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\web3\middleware\attrdict.py", line 33, in middleware
        response = make_request(method, params)
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
        response = make_request(method, params)
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
        response = make_request(method, params)
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
        response = make_request(method, params)
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\web3\middleware\buffered_gas_estimate.py", line 40, in middleware
        return make_request(method, params)
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\web3\middleware\exception_retry_request.py", line 105, in middleware
        return make_request(method, params)
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\web3\providers\rpc.py", line 88, in make_request
        raw_response = make_post_request(
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\web3\_utils\request.py", line 103, in make_post_request
        response.raise_for_status()
      File "C:\Users\Project\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 960, in raise_for_status
        raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
    HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/PROJECT_ID
```

I am getting an error in the .env file it wasted my two days still I cant figure out

Comment: Looks like it is not getting the right `PROJECT_ID` since it has that right in the URL that gives 401. Either you need to define that env var or change how you are generating the URL in your code.

Comment: i am pasting id from infura

Comment: source env is also not working

Answer (score 0):

You added a new network incorrectly. You are trying to send requests literally to 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/PROJECT_ID'. PROJECT_ID is not a placeholder in your case, it is part of the URL.

Update your network URL (see [brownie network management](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/network-management.html)):

```
brownie networks modify rinkeby host='https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/$PROJECT_ID'
```

Replace 'rinkeby' with the name of the network you are using. Besides, you can try using the full url from Infura (to troubleshoot):

```
brownie networks modify rinkeby host='https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/0gg81053a4...ad
```